# MySql LongText unselectable with value > 32kb

Tags: c#, mysql, connector, longtext

I use MySql Server 5.1. I have a MySql table with a longtext column. I'm writing a program in C# 2010 using MySql Connector 6.3.1 and I want to select that column in my program using regular linq.

I have inserted some text using MySql Workbench. As long as the text is <32kb, I can select it in my program. As soon as this text is > 32kb, I get this error:

*InnerException: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
       Message=Non-negative number required.
Parameter name: count
       Source=mscorlib
       ParamName=count*

I have no idea how to solve this one. Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a MySQL Connector bug. [This report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54040) claims it is fixed in 6.3.2.

Comment: Thanks! Installing 6.3.2 indeed fixed the problem. :)